# Websocket request fails due to 400. - bad request in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a websocket request generated during jmeter recording with 400- bad request status in recording log when observed during login, but when I observed in chrome dev tools it is getting 101- switching protocols.

Here requests also different in jmeter compared to dev tools

Dev tool

Request url: wss://app.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket
Request method: GET
Status code: 101 Switching protocol

Jmeter recording & replay log

Request url: https://app.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket
Request method: GET
Status code: 400 bad request

Answer (score 0):

You cannot record WebSocket requests using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

As it evidenced by its name it can only record [HTTP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) or [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTTPS) requests, [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) is a different beast and JMeter doesn't support it out of the box.

You might want to install [JMeter WebSocket Samplers](https://github.com/Luminis-Arnhem/jmeter-websocket-samplers) plugin and put the request and payload there.

More information: [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers)